# JSF2+PF: Update dialog header when it opens or shows

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, dialog, modal-dialog

Is there a way to update the dialog header text when it opens? I used to use the `dynamic` attribute and set it to true. But due to issues with Form and Bean state (the dialog has a form inside), I had to abandon its usage. There is a hook to the js attribute `onShow` but I'm not sure how to update the header text from there.

Here is a simplified version of what my dialog looks like. It is defined as a composite component (not shown):

```
<composite:interface componentType="addEditDialog">
...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:dialog>
        <f:facet name="header">
            #{cc.headerText}
        </f:facet>
        ....
    </p:dialog>
     ...
</composite:implementation>
```

I have some custom code in the backing NamingContainer class that determines the actual header text when it is opened:

```
@FacesComponent("addEditDialog")
public class AddEditCompositeComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    public String getHeaderText() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wrapping the header text in a PF outputPanel with autoUpdate=true and it works for me.

```
<p:dialog>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">#{cc.headerText}</p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    ....
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: thanks it solved my problem of auto update of header. I had been trying  <h:outputText> but that didn't work

Comment: i have a problem however. I click on any other action button inside my dialog the header of the dialog gets autoupdated. How can I avoid that?